vscode codespace - how to install neovim and configure vscode-neovim
I followed the suggestons from chatGPT ai and created this devcontainer.json file inside .devcontainer

{
    "name": "rustflow",
    "image": "rust:latest",
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "rust-lang.rust-analyzer",
                "serayuzgur.crates",
                "tamasfe.even-better-toml",
                "vadimcn.vscode-lldb",
                "HenryTsz.nvim"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/fish",  // Set Fish as the default shell
                "rust-analyzer.checkOnSave.command": "clippy",
                "editor.formatOnSave": true
            }
        }
    },
    "initializeCommand": "apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common && add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/stable && apt-get update && apt-get install -y neovim fish",
    "postCreateCommand": "fish -c 'curl -sL https://git.io/fisher | source && fisher install jorgebucaran/fisher && fisher install IlanCosman/tide && echo y | tide configure' && rustup component add clippy rustfmt && cargo build",
    "runArgs": [
        "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE",
        "--security-opt",
        "seccomp=unconfined"
    ],
    "containerUser": "vscode",
    "remoteUser": "vscode"
}

The codespace configuration runs without any errors, but...,

None of the extensions is installed.
neovim is not installed

This is the output while building the codespace container..
Host information

----------------

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (stable release)

Image details: https://github.com/github/codespaces-host-images/blob/main/README.md

----------------

Configuration starting...

Cloning...

Using image: mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal

Creating container...

Cleaning up docker images...

$ devcontainer up --id-label Type=codespaces --workspace-folder /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/rustflow --mount type=bind,source=/.codespaces/agent/mount/cache,target=/vscode --user-data-folder /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/.persistedshare --container-data-folder .vscode-remote/data/Machine --container-system-data-folder /var/vscode-remote --log-level trace --log-format json --update-remote-user-uid-default never --mount-workspace-git-root false --omit-config-remote-env-from-metadata --skip-non-blocking-commands --skip-post-create --remove-existing-container --override-config /root/.codespaces/shared/merged_devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --container-session-data-folder /workspaces/.codespaces/.persistedshare/devcontainers-cli/cache --secrets-file /root/.codespaces/shared/user-secrets-envs.json

[206 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.68.0. Node.js v18.20.4. linux 6.5.0-1025-azure x64.

[935 ms] Start: Run: docker run --sig-proxy=false -a STDOUT -a STDERR --mount type=bind,src=/var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace,dst=/workspaces --mount type=volume,src=dind-var-lib-docker-0hcbhh2c7vldoj773drm1bjldnb89u0rt96sl9nju22d9ou8d14n,dst=/var/lib/docker --mount type=volume,src=minikube-config,dst=/home/vscode/.minikube --mount source=/root/.codespaces/shared,target=/workspaces/.codespaces/shared,type=bind --mount source=/var/lib/docker/codespacemount/.persistedshare,target=/workspaces/.codespaces/.persistedshare,type=bind --mount source=/.codespaces/agent/mount,target=/.codespaces/bin,type=bind --mount source=/mnt/containerTmp,target=/tmp,type=bind --mount type=bind,src=/.codespaces/agent/mount/cache,dst=/vscode -l Type=codespaces -e CODESPACES=******** -e ContainerVersion=13 -e RepositoryName=rustflow -u codespace --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --privileged --init --label CodespacesImageType=Default --label ContainerVersion=13 --hostname codespaces-89cf7f --add-host codespaces-89cf7f:127.0.0.1 --cap-add sys_nice --network host --init --privileged --cap-add SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --entrypoint /bin/sh -l devcontainer.metadata=[{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/common-utils:2"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git:1"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/dotnet:2"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/hugo:1"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/node:1"},{"id":"./local-features/nvs"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/conda:1"},{"id":"./local-features/patch-conda"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/php:1"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/ruby:1"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/java:1"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/sshd:1","entrypoint":"/usr/local/share/ssh-init.sh"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git-lfs:1","postCreateCommand":"/usr/local/share/pull-git-lfs-artifacts.sh"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/github-cli:1"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-in-docker:2","privileged":********,"entrypoint":"/usr/local/share/docker-init.sh","mounts":[{"source":"dind-var-lib-docker-${devcontainerId}","target":"/var/lib/docker","type":"volume"}]},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/kubectl-helm-minikube:1","mounts":[{"source":"minikube-config","target":"/home/vscode/.minikube","type":"volume"}]},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/go:1","init":********,"capAdd":["SYS_PTRACE"],"securityOpt":["seccomp=unconfined"]},{"id":"./local-features/jekyll"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/oryx:1"},{"id":"ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/python:1"},{"id":"./local-features/patch-python"},{"id":"./local-features/machine-learning-packages"},{"id":"./local-features/setup-user"},{"customizations":{"vscode":{"settings":{"go.toolsManagement.checkForUpdates":"local","go.useLanguageServer":********,"go.gopath":"/go","python.defaultInterpreterPath":"/home/codespace/.python/current/bin/python3","jupyter.kernels.filter":[{"path":"/opt/conda/bin/python","type":"pythonEnvironment"},{"path":"/usr/local/python/current/bin/python3","type":"pythonEnvironment"},{"path":"/usr/local/python/current/bin/python","type":"pythonEnvironment"},{"path":"/usr/bin/python3","type":"pythonEnvironment"},{"path":"/bin/python3","type":"pythonEnvironment"}],"lldb.executable":"/usr/bin/lldb"},"extensions":["GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github"]}},"containerUser":"codespace","remoteUser":"codespace"},{"customizations":{"vscode":{"settings":{"go.toolsManagement.checkForUpdates":"local","go.useLanguageServer":********,"go.gopath":"/go","python.defaultInterpreterPath":"/home/codespace/.python/current/bin/python3","jupyter.kernels.filter":[{"path":"/opt/conda/bin/python","type":"pythonEnvironment"},{"path":"/bin/python2","type":"pythonEnvironment"},{"path":"/usr/bin/python2","type":"pythonEnvironment"},{"path":"/usr/local/python/current/bin/python3","type":"pythonEnvironment"},{"path":"/usr/local/python/current/bin/python","type":"pythonEnvironment"},{"path":"/usr/bin/python3","type":"pythonEnvironment"},{"path":"/bin/python3","type":"pythonEnvironment"}],"lldb.executable":"/usr/bin/lldb"}}},"mounts":["source=/root/.codespaces/shared,target=/workspaces/.codespaces/shared,type=bind","source=/var/lib/docker/codespacemount/.persistedshare,target=/workspaces/.codespaces/.persistedshare,type=bind","source=/.codespaces/agent/mount,target=/.codespaces/bin,type=bind","source=/mnt/containerTmp,target=/tmp,type=bind"],"containerEnv":{"CODESPACES":"********","ContainerVersion":"13","RepositoryName":"rustflow"},"remoteUser":"codespace","overrideCommand":false}] mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal:latest -c echo Container started

Unable to find image 'mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal:latest' locally

latest: Pulling from devcontainers/universal

602d8ad51b81: Pull complete 

849d9d8bdd96: Pull complete 

d8feefc5240a: Pull complete 

a268b0b27052: Pull complete 

ab9af81f7a3c: Pull complete 

1dbfb8b1916c: Pull complete 

a52e3b375417: Pull complete 

4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete 

eae314a1a34d: Pull complete 

365980cbaf79: Pull complete 

4ea7bc6fc41b: Pull complete 

fee6644f505a: Pull complete 

826202c0febc: Pull complete 

fb2f6463a534: Pull complete 

e2daff9d5037: Pull complete 

45916ccac885: Pull complete 

ac0e6e5c9534: Pull complete 

60d6f07b8621: Pull complete 

6943e00e4c85: Pull complete 

9914bdd2fa72: Pull complete 

c2a03a1c2426: Pull complete 

570d206b83d2: Pull complete 

bb7f6c2a2001: Pull complete 

98d41d8b5bc9: Pull complete 

924e4b35ad64: Pull complete 

e03225c7ce75: Pull complete 

de889d4d2a65: Pull complete 

73ad3041008a: Pull complete 

a78777c0eda1: Pull complete 

f340cf4bee9c: Pull complete 

d8e855a198fa: Pull complete 

4599cc35b383: Pull complete 

a7509c7a2d5c: Pull complete 

6b5056250924: Pull complete 

01e38d152d84: Pull complete 

Digest: sha256:aa2fbe1e4faea9f4e68437d3ff6168935d77d0d425fb6ee8985bea50c0371fac

Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/universal:latest

Container started

Outcome: success User: codespace WorkspaceFolder: /workspaces/rustflow

devcontainer process exited with exit code 0

Running blocking commands...

$ devcontainer up --id-label Type=codespaces --workspace-folder /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/rustflow --mount type=bind,source=/.codespaces/agent/mount/cache,target=/vscode --user-data-folder /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/.persistedshare --container-data-folder .vscode-remote/data/Machine --container-system-data-folder /var/vscode-remote --log-level trace --log-format json --update-remote-user-uid-default never --mount-workspace-git-root false --omit-config-remote-env-from-metadata --skip-non-blocking-commands --expect-existing-container --override-config /root/.codespaces/shared/merged_devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --container-session-data-folder /workspaces/.codespaces/.persistedshare/devcontainers-cli/cache --secrets-file /root/.codespaces/shared/user-secrets-envs.json

[421 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.68.0. Node.js v18.20.4. linux 6.5.0-1025-azure x64.

Outcome: success User: codespace WorkspaceFolder: /workspaces/rustflow

devcontainer process exited with exit code 0

Configuring codespace...

Running oryx...

Running commands...

$ devcontainer up --id-label Type=codespaces --workspace-folder /var/lib/docker/codespacemount/workspace/rustflow --expect-existing-container --skip-post-attach --mount type=bind,source=/.codespaces/agent/mount/cache,target=/vscode --container-data-folder .vscode-remote/data/Machine --container-system-data-folder /var/vscode-remote --log-level trace --log-format json --update-remote-user-uid-default never --mount-workspace-git-root false --override-config /root/.codespaces/shared/merged_devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --container-session-data-folder /workspaces/.codespaces/.persistedshare/devcontainers-cli/cache --secrets-file /root/.codespaces/shared/user-secrets-envs.json

[195 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.68.0. Node.js v18.20.4. linux 6.5.0-1025-azure x64.

Running the postCreateCommand from Feature 'ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git-lfs:1'...



/usr/local/share/pull-git-lfs-artifacts.sh

Fetching git lfs artifacts...

Outcome: success User: codespace WorkspaceFolder: /workspaces/rustflow

devcontainer process exited with exit code 0


